# Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'initialize'

Tags: javascript, html, events, typeerror

I am getting has no method error

here is the sample code

```
var snake = function(){

    this.initialize = function(){
        // initalize
    };
    this.start = function() {
        this.initialize();
    };

};

var s = new snake();

var startButton = document.getElementByID("start");

startButton.addEventListener('click',s.start,false);
```

So when I click start button I am getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'initialize'

how can i fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
startButtons.addEventListener('click', function() { s.start() }, false);
```

The `this` in the function is going to be the input unless you use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score 0):

Because of [`this`](http://devdocs.io/javascript/operators/this). Use a private variable(`snk`) to ensure you are accessing the snake:

```
var snake = function(){

    var snk = this;

    this.initialize = function(){
        // initalize
    };

    this.start = function() {
        snk.initialize();
    };
};

var s = new snake();

var startButton = document.getElementByID("start");

startButton.addEventListener('click',s.start,false);
```